# Programmatically add ajax behavior in actionlistener

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces, jsf-2

Our project is build on top of JSF 2.3 and Primefaces 6.2.
We make heavy use of the Primefaces dialog framework.
A typical commandButton to open a dialog looks like this:

```
<p:commandButton id="editButton" icon="fa fa-edit" value="Edit" disabled="#{empty interfaceIpDialogBean.selectedAddress}"
                 actionListener="#{interfaceIpDialogBean.onEditIpAddress}">
    <p:ajax event="dialogReturn" listener="#{interfaceIpDialogBean.onEditIpAddressResult}" update="@form"/>
</p:commandButton>
```

In the button listener `onEditIpAddress` a call to the Primefaces dialog framework will open the modal dialog.
To get the result back from the dialog after closing it primefaces uses the ajax event "dialogReturn" which have to be added to the commandButton.

Now we want to use this pattern in a more dynamic way. We dont want to register an ajax event on each button which could possibly open a dialog. We created a dialog service which uses callbacks which will be called after the dialog closes.

But we still need the additional ajax call on the button to update the ui of the callee after the dialog closes.

My question is:
Is it possible to register the ajax behavior on the commandButton inside the actionListener `onEditIpAddress` ?
Or can we somehow use the Primefaces javascript library to trigger an ajax partial update after the ajax call which closes the dialog?

Each idea is welcome ;-)

Comment: Why not create a `my:compositeButton` that contains the ajax ?

Comment: What you're proposing will have you freshly attach the behaviour to the command button on every single invocation.